# Add, Delete, Edit Rows and Columns while Iterating PANDAS DATAFRAME

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with over 50,000 tweets that I open as DataFrame with Pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset_tweets.csv')
```

[image]

My goal is to Analyze the sentiment of the tweets, and before proceeding, I need to normalize the tweet.
I have defined a function for that, and I would like to add the output as a new column of the dataframe (e.g. Text_Normalized).

Nevertheless, I may also need to delete the row if it meets certain conditions (e.g. if the tweet is not written in English).

How do I iterate through the dataframe, apply the "normalizer" function to the text column, delete the row if it did not meet certain criteria and eventually add a new column with the text normalized?

Comment: Check out [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).  
Also, you wrote, "delete the column if it did not meet certain criteria": Do you mean "delete the row"?  Or do you want to remove the entire column if one entry fails?

Comment: I mean delete the row if the tweet is not written in english

Comment: If my answer answers your question, accept it, so I can get that delicious karma :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say you have some 'text normalising' function:

```
def normalises_text(text):
    ....
    return normalised_text
```

You can apply this 'row-wise' to your 'text' column and put this in a new column very simply , as follows:

```
df['normalised_text'] = df.text.apply(normalises_text)
```

to remove rows which don't fit some criteria, you need a way to define your criteria in the dataframe.

Say you defined a function which identified whether text is English, and returns a boolean:

```
def is_text_english(text):
    ....
    return text_is_english
```

Then put this in a column as before:

```
df['text_is_english'] = df.text.apply(is_text_english)
```

Then, you could filter your dataframe as follows:

```
filtered_df = df[df.text_is_english]
```

Or, say you had a column which states the language of the tweet, you could do:

```
filtered_df = df[df.tweet_language == 'EN']
```

The key point here is the apply function:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: It did the job! Thank you :)